# SQL Server - how to insert values into tables that reference each other

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database

Trying to insert into the MS SQL Database, but I am struck by this error:

INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Original error (in german)

```
pypyodbc.IntegrityError: (u'23000', u'[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Die INSERT-Anweisung steht in Konflikt mit der FOREIGN KEY-Einschr\xe4nkung "FK_tCompanyLocation_tCompany". Der Konflikt trat in der Test-Datenbank, Tabelle "dbo.tCompany", column \'GUID\' auf.')
```

Now .... I think I get the error ... while inserting into tCompanyLocation, company_guid (GUID) will be not in tCompany table, since it will be inserted in my script as second. However tCompany also needs company_location_guid (LocationGUID), so I cannot execute it before ....

This seems to me like a chicken & egg problem... I cannot insert into tCompany due to tCompanyLocation and vice versa.

```
import uuid
import pypyodbc

company_guid = uuid.uuid4()
company_guid = str(company_guid).upper()
company_location_guid = uuid.uuid4()
company_location_guid = str(company_location_guid).upper()
position_guid = uuid.uuid4()
position_guid = str(position_guid).upper()
department_guid = uuid.uuid4()
department_guid= str(department_guid).upper()
experience_guid = uuid.uuid4()
experience_guid = str(experience_guid).upper()
people_guid = uuid.uuid4()
people_guid = str(people_guid).upper()

cnxn = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=Test;UID=sa;PWD=password')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()


def insert_company_location():

    sql = """
    INSERT
    INTO[dbo].[tCompanyLocation]
    ([GUID]
     , [CompanyGUID]
     , [LocationName]
     , [Address1]
     , [Address2]
     , [City]
     , [Zipcode]
     , [Phone]
     , [Fax]
     , [TimeEntered]
     , [TimeUpdated]
     , [UserEnteredGUID]
     , [UserUpdatedGUID]
     , [UpdateHistory]
     , [PhoneCountryCode]
     , [FaxCountryCode]
     , [CountryGUID]
     , [CompanyLocationNotes]
     , [RegionGUID]
     , [Region2GUID])

VALUES
( """ + "\'" + company_location_guid + "\'" + """
, """ + "\'" + company_guid + "\'" + """
, 'New York, NY'
, 'Street 1'
, 'Street 2'
, 'New York'
, '10165'
, '+12121234123'
, '+12129124123'
, '2009-01-01 14:47:05.250'
, '2009-01-01 14:47:05.250'
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, '1'
, NULL
, '25B825CF-BDD0-11D5-93E2-00D0B7471F8B'
, NULL
, 'D2490D0A-140D-4D52-A57E-47909B6C222B'
, NULL)
"""
    print(sql)
    cursor.execute(sql)

def insert_company():

    sql = """

    INSERT
    INTO[dbo].[tCompany]
    ([GUID]
     , [CompanyTypeGUID]
     , [BranchOfGUID]
     , [CurrencyGUID]
     , [CompanyName]
     , [PrintName]
     , [LocationGUID]
     , [Website]
     , [FeePercent]
     , [FeeAmount]
     , [FeeNotes]
     , [Bio]
     , [CompanyNotes]
     , [CompanyDoNotPrint]
     , [CompanyCode]
     , [AlertMessage]
     , [TimeEntered]
     , [UserEnteredGUID]
     , [TimeUpdated]
     , [UserUpdatedGUID]
     , [UpdateHistory]
     , [CompanyLocationNotes]
     , [ExternalDocument])


VALUES
(  """ + "\'" + company_guid + "\'" + """
, NULL
, NULL
, '2104105B-31CA-11D4-BC2A-0050DA246141'
, 'IBM'
, NULL
, """ + "\'" + company_location_guid + "\'" + """
, 'http://www.ibm.com'
, '0.0000'
, '0,00'
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, '0'
, NULL
, NULL
, '2010-01-01 11:30:52.780'
, 'C9678062-0E21-4E2A-9707-4564E00B8678'
, '2010-02-01 11:31:53.000'
, 'C9678062-0E21-4E2A-9707-4564E00B8678'
, NULL
, NULL
, '0')
"""
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

**Question:**

How to solve this issue? I know generating GUIDs from Python is bad, but how can I achieve it without doing it in Python? If somebody can show me, how to insert into those 2 tables, it would be great.

Comment: I question the design decision of having `LocationGUID` in the `tCompany` table.  `CompanyGUID` is already in the `tCompanyLocation` table and that is the proper relationship.  The design you have now will force a 1:1 relationship between Company and CompanyLocation.  Is it an option to change the design or the constraints?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot modify the database structure/design. Any ideas how to solve my problem? Or is it unsolveable :( ? I am new to MS SQL Server and DB Design ... worked moslty with simple DBs in MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: In that case, is there a constraint on the `LocationGUID` column in the `tCompany` table?  If not, you can create the `Company` record first putting a temporary value in the `LocationGUID` column, then insert the `tCompanyLocation` record with the new `CompanyGUID` value, then go back and update the `LocationGUID` column in `tCompany` with the correct value.  If there is a constraint on both tables for the GUIDs, then I would really, really push for the constraint to be dropped on the `tCompany` table as it will be impossible to add records that way,

Comment: THANKS YOU VERY VERY MUCH!!! I think I got your point. The constraint is there "FK_tCompany_tCompanyLocation" on tCompany table where PRI tCompanyLocation GUID is connected to FK tcompany LocationGUID. After I removed this constraint, it seemed to work. Is my example is generating GUID in Python a good idea? How can I make sure that generated GUID does not exist already? How can I solve problem on unique GUID generation that I can share accross queries as a Python variable? Any ideas?

Comment: Good - glad it's working.  Generating a GUID from Python isn't *bad*, but I tend to not like letting my language do stuff like that.  I tend to let the database do that like through Identity columns or NEWID (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx)).  To ensure unique GUID, you can do a simple lookup inside your `insert_company` function to check the existence of the GUID first (also other things like company name, etc). and handle if it already exists.  Not exactly sure what you mean on your last question - I'd suggest maybe a new post on that here.